# need to SELECT and show all entries written by specific user and count it

Tags: php, mysql

I need to SELECT and show all entries written by specific user and number of his/her total entries

```
<?php  include 'helperl.php';  include 'dbconn.php';

$name=$_GET['id'];
$sql="SELECT * FROM entries WHERE writer_user LIKE '%$name%'";
$result=$conn->query($sql);
$num_entry= count($result); 
echo "$num_entry"; 
?>
```

Comment: What happens with this code? You are open to SQL injections. Maybe you need `count(*)` in place of `*` and then to fetch..

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: I need example SQL

Comment: Yes I know it is not secure and that is for another question

Comment: You've written SQL already. What happens with the code you have here?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. Please learn to use [prepared statements](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First the LIKE option that you did will get you all the name that contain `$user`

Your query should be like

```
SELECT nb
FROM (SELECT writer_user,count(*) as nb
      FROM entries 
      WHERE writer_user=you_var
      Group BY writer_user)
```

For getting all the entries of specific user

```
SELECT * 
FROM entries 
WHERE writer_user=you_var
```

u can do a join in one query to get the information you wanted but there will be a duplication in the count attribut.

exemple :

**entrie**      **count**

entrie1       4

entrie2       4

entrie3       4

entrie4       4

**hope i helped you.**

Answer (score 0):

you should use SQL COUNT function to do this ([SQL COUNT function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/counting-rows.html) 
)

#### COUNT() Syntax

```
SELECT COUNT(column_name)
FROM table_name
WHERE condition;
```

#### Your code can look like this

```
<?php

try {

    $name = htmlentities(strip_tags($_GET['id']));

    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(writer_user) as counter FROM entries WHERE writer_user LIKE '%$name%'";

    // create pdf instance
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    // prepare sql and bind parameters
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(writer_user) as counter FROM entries WHERE writer_user LIKE '%name%'");
    $stmt->bindParam('name', $name);
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $conn->query($stmt)->fetchAll();

    var_dump($result);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
?>
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. Please learn to use [prepared statements](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY).

Comment: well thats not my code. its a copy of user2560303 example snipped and i added toDos for him to do this (see code comments). BUT i will fix it

Comment: you dont need to escape the input, if you are using a prepared statement